# Is <windows.h> in collision with "raylib.h" library

Tags: c, include

I am trying to build a game in C language using `raylib` library and I wanted to deploy the `sleep` function that is defined in  library.  The latter generates a problem in the build of `raylib` library

Comment: `raylib.h` doesn't seem to have a sleep function. What exactly is the problem your are seeing? https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/raylib.h

Comment: i wanted to deploy the sleep function that is built under <windows.h>, we i try to build the project it generates errors in the actual raylib library

Comment: If you sleep is the only function you need from Windows.h then try `_sleep()` from `stdlib.h` instead. See this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/70d6b00b-9708-4d94-893f-0f3ae7b3ef20/sleepint?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: I have added the same as an answer. If this worked you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If `sleep` is the only function you need from Windows.h then use `_sleep()` from `stdlib.h` instead. Check this [MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/70d6b00b-9708-4d94-893f-0f3ae7b3ef20/sleepint?forum=vcgeneral) for further reference.

Comment: No, there is nothing called `_sleep` in `stdlib.h`. This is some compiler-specific non-standard extension and the OP didn't mention a compiler.

Comment: Updated the answer for reference

Comment: @Lundin OP says `Windows.h`, I think that is evident enough that he is using Visual Studio (VC++)

Comment: Not at all, every Windows compiler uses that header.

Comment: Also I just realized there is no function called `sleep` in Windows, that's the POSIX version. Which uses seconds, not ms.

Comment: Apart from that, you are recommending an obsolete function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/obsolete-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have two headers, header1.h and header2.h, both containing a function named foo. Then you can define a new header/source pair:

mynewheader.h:

```
int header2_foo(int n);
```

mynewheader.c:

```
#include <header2.h>
int header2_foo(int n) {
    return foo(n);
}
```

Of course, you can choose any prefix you want, or rename the function completely for that matter. This kind of mimics the namespace feature in C++.